# Receiving error 'The provided key element does not match the schema' while using put_item on dynamodb table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My code is here:

```
    try:
            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for i in range(len(rows)):
                    print(int(rows[i]['cust_id']))
                    print(int(rows[i]['prdct_id']))
                    batch.put_item(
                                        Item={
                                            
                                            'cust_id': {'N':rows[i]['cust_id']},
                                            'prdct_id': {'N':rows[i]['prdct_id']}
                                            
                                            }
                                        )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Where I have defined cust_id as partition key on my table. Can someone please help?

Comment: What is your schema?

Comment: It just has cust_id defined as partition key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. The format written in the question is "dynamodb" format. Which basically means that its annotated with types (annoyingly). This is necessary for creating the tables, but batch_write was expecting json format. It should look like this:

```
    try:
            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for i in range(len(rows)):
                    
                    batch.put_item(
                                        Item={
                                            
                                            "cust_id": int(rows[i]['cust_id']),
                                            "prdct_id": rows[i]['prdct_id']
                                            
                                            }
                                        )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```